# how to run two django projects with different python versions

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run multiple python version on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows)

i want to run two django projects at the same time on a single os (windows) simultaneously.
both projects has different python versions.

here i want to run two django projects simultaneously on the machine. i don't know how it is possible because both projects runs with different version of python language. im currently running project with python version 2.5. but how can i run another project with different python version. because windows is dealing with only one version of python which is 2.5 .

Comment: You just asked this and got it answered... You need to explain exactly what you are doing and why it doens't work.

Comment: this is a different question. here i want to run two django projects simultaneously on the machine. i don't know how it is possible because both projects runs with different version of python language. im currently running project with python version 2.5. but how can i run another project with different python version. because windows is dealing with only one version of python which is 2.5 .

Comment: No, it's the same question. The answer is also the same: You run it with C:\Python-2.5\Python.exe or C:\Python-2.6\Python.exe depending on what version you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I'll answer the question *again*.

To use two versions, you install both alongside each other in different directories, as the installer on Windows will do, by default. To run one project with Python 2.5, you install and run it by using the Python.exe installed in the Python 2.5 directory. And to run the other project you run and install it by using the Python.exe installed in the 2.6 directory.

So when the Django documentation tels you to run "python setup.py install" you instead write "C:\Python25\Python.exe setup.py install" or "C:\Python26\Python.exe setup.py install".

It **really** is that simple.

Comment: thanks a lot. its really a simple solution. but im still insisting that my both questions are different. though u answered both ones. one questions only deals with running multiple python versions and another deals with running multiple django projects. solution seems similar in both cases. but expert like you can see problems with better perspective as compare to beginners like me :-)

Comment: Yeah, the solution is similar, because the question is the same.