# How to make shortcut work from PATH

Tags: python, windows, path

I have two versions of Python on Windows and want to use them through `cmd`. I tried to make shortcuts of their `python.exe` and renaming them to `python26` and `python33` (I also added their locations to `PATH`), but unfortunately this does not work. Calling `python26` or `python26.lnk` outputs in `not recognized as an internal command`.

Is there any other way to do it (like Linux virtualenv), or I missed something in my idea ?

Comment: Can you just add two batch files and use complete path in them?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245619/2235132)?

Comment: Rename the executables from `python.exe` to `python2.exe` and add both `C:\Python26\ ` and `C:\Python33\ ` to your **PATH**

Comment: @Ihuang - sorry, but I quite don't understand what you are trying to say - do I have to create two batch files and add to each one complete path to each python ?

Comment: @devnull - I want to execute specific python from cmd. I am not trying to force python files to find specific python for themselfs - but thanks for good link - it will come handy someday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run multiple python version on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows)

Comment: @Torxed - this will work but I wanted to leave python.exe as the way it is, and operate on shortucts or some virual enviroment systems

Comment: @lagoru How about saying `set py26=\path\to\python2.6` and invoking by saying `%py26%`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new .bat file under `C:\imagaginary_path\` and name it `python2.bat`.
Within the bat file write:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe %*
```

Then create another one under `C:\imagaginary_path\` and name it `python3.bat`.
With the content:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe %*
```

Now remove `C:\Python26\` and `C:\Python33\` from your `PATH` and instead place `C:\imaginary_path\` in your `PATH` variable.

There, Windows treats .bat files as executables, and now you can call `python2 test.py`
Now every time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> You will get a promt asking "Terminate batch job ?" which is kind of annoying, there's a few alternatives in order to solve this and one being you edit your python2.bat to look like:

```
start C:\Python26\python.exe %*
```

Comment: or simply place the two `.bat` files under `C:\Windows\System32\`, works just as well.

Comment: No! Don't put files into system32, that directory belongs to the system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yea because windows file-structure is so sacred (although i agree, that's why i put it as a comment and not in my answer, but it would work and you wouldn't need to modify the PATH).

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, creating a batch file works fine. But if you still want to use normal shortcuts (`.lnk` files) you can modify your `PATHEXT` environment variable to include `.LNK`. This variable tells Windows what extensions to treat as executable files when searching through the `PATH` variable.

For example, after creating a shortcut and adding its folder to `PATH`, this works:

```
C:\>python27
'python27' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\>set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.LNK

C:\>python27
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z


C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also work with Windows path:

```
set path=C:\Python26;.;..;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32
prompt $ & start title Python26
```

Save this as Py26.bat and type Python in the screen that displays

```
set path=C:\Python33;.;..;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32
prompt $ & start title Python33
```

Save this as Py33.bat and type Python in the screen that displays

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating shortcuts, what you could do is to change the name of python.exe itself.

So you could rename the python.exe in C:\Python26\ to 'python2', and the python.exe in C:\Python33\ to 'python3'. Given that most of the Python code right now is in < Python3, an efficient alternative would be to just change the Python 3.3 python.exe file to be 'python3', and leave the Python 2.6 one unchanged. This way, you would be able to specify if you wanted to run something using python3.

Now edit the %PATH% environment variable to include both C:\Python26\ and C:\Python33.

Example:

```
python3 chunky_bacon_FTW.py
```

would run using Python3.3.