# How to update Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, upgrade, windows-7-x64

I have version 2.7 installed from early 2012. I can't find any consensus on whether I should completely uninstall and wipe this version before putting on the latest version.

"Soft"-removing old versions? Hard-removing/wiping old versions? Installing over top?

I've seen somewhere a special install/upgrade process using a "segmenting" method of Python installations, keeping different versions separate and apart, but functional. Not sure if this is the standard, de facto way.

I also wonder if Revo gets too overzealous and may cause issues with wiping out still-needed remnants, like environment/PATH variables.

(Win7 x64, 32-bit Python)

Comment: 2.7 is still the latest version—in the 2.x series, anyway.  3.x is backwards-incompatible.  if you want to upgrade to the current 2.7 release, i'd just install over top.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**UPDATE**: 2018-07-06

This post is now nearly 5 years old! [Python-2.7 will stop receiving official updates from python.org in 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/). Also, [Python-3.7 has been released](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/). Check out [Python-Future](http://python-future.org/) on how to make your Python-2 code compatible with Python-3. For updating conda, the documentation now recommends using `conda update --all` in each of your conda environments to update all packages and the Python executable for that version. Also, since they changed their name to Anaconda, I don't know if the Windows registry keys are still the same.

**UPDATE**: 2017-03-24

There have been no updates to Python(x,y) since June of 2015, so I think it's safe to assume it has been abandoned.

**UPDATE**: 2016-11-11

As [@cxw comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102943/how-to-update-python/17954487#comment68062745_17954487), these answers are for the same bit-versions, and by bit-version I mean 64-bit vs. 32-bit. For example, these answers would apply to updating from 64-bit Python-2.7.10 to 64-bit Python-2.7.11, *ie*: the **same** bit-version. While it is possible to install two different bit versions of Python together, it would require some hacking, so I'll save that exercise for the reader. If you don't want to hack, I suggest that if switching bit-versions, remove the other bit-version first.

**UPDATES**: 2016-05-16

- [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#windows-install) and [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html#windows-miniconda-install) can be used with an existing Python installation by disabling the options to alter the Windows `PATH` and Registry. After extraction, create a symlink to `conda` in your `bin` or install conda from PyPI. Then create another symlink called `conda-activate` to `activate` in the Anaconda/Miniconda root bin folder. Now Anaconda/Miniconda is just like Ruby RVM. Just use `conda-activate root` to enable Anaconda/Miniconda.
- Portable Python is no longer being developed or maintained.

## TL;DR

- Using [Anaconda or miniconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/), then just execute `conda update --all` to keep each conda environment updated,
- **same *major* version of [official Python](https://www.python.org/)** (*e.g.* 2.7.5), just install over old (*e.g.* 2.7.4),
- **different *major* version of [official Python](https://www.python.org/)** (*e.g.* 3.3), install side-by-side with old, set paths/associations to point to dominant (*e.g.* 2.7), shortcut to other (*e.g.* in BASH `$ ln /c/Python33/python.exe python3`).

#### The answer depends:

1. If OP has 2.7.x and wants to install newer version of 2.7.x, then

   - if using [MSI installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) from the [official Python website](http://www.python.org/download/), just install over old version, installer will issue warning that it will remove and replace the older version; looking in "installed programs" in "control panel" before and after confirms that the old version has been replaced by the new version; newer versions of 2.7.x are backwards compatible so this is completely safe and therefore IMHO multiple versions of 2.7.x should never necessary.
   - if building from source, then you should probably build in a fresh, clean directory, and then point your path to the new build once it passes all tests and you are confident that it has been built successfully, but you may wish to keep the old build around because building from source may occasionally have issues. See my [guide for building Python x64 on Windows 7 with SDK 7.0](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2015/03/building-python-x64-on-windows-7-with.html).
   - if installing from a distribution such as [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/), see their website. **[Python(x,y)](http://python-xy.github.io/) has been abandoned.** <s>I believe that updates can be handled from within Python(x,y) with their package manager, but [updates are also included on their website](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads#Updates). I could not find a specific reference so perhaps someone else can speak to this. Similar to ActiveState and probably Enthought, Python (x,y) clearly states it is incompatible with other installations of Python:</s>

     > It is recommended to uninstall any other Python distribution before installing Python(x,y)
   - [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/downloads/) uses an MSI and will install either into `Program Files\Enthought` or `home\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App` for all users or per user respectively. Newer installations are updated by using the built in update tool. See their [documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_windows.html).
   - [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) also uses an MSI so newer installations can be installed on top of older ones. See their [installation notes](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/installnotes.html#msi).

     > Other Python 2.7 Installations On Windows, ActivePython 2.7 cannot coexist with other Python 2.7 installations (for example, a Python 2.7 build from python.org). Uninstall any other Python 2.7 installations before installing ActivePython 2.7.
   - [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/download-windows.html) recommends that you install it into a virtual machine, and provides a Oracle VirtualBox image file that can be used for this purpose. Upgrades are handled internally by issuing the `sage -upgrade` command.
   - [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) can be [updated by using the `conda` command](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#updating-from-older-anaconda-versions):

     ```
     conda update --all
     ```

     Anaconda/Miniconda lets users create *environments* to manage multiple Python versions including Python-2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5. The root Anaconda/Miniconda installations are currently based on either Python-2.7 or Python-3.5.

     <s>Anaconda will likely disrupt any other Python installations. Installation uses MSI installer.</s>
     [**UPDATE**: 2016-05-16] *Anaconda and Miniconda now use `.exe` installers and provide options to disable Windows `PATH` and Registry alterations.*

     Therefore Anaconda/Miniconda can be installed without disrupting existing Python installations depending on how it was installed and the options that were selected during installation. If the `.exe` installer is used and the options to alter Windows `PATH` and Registry are *not* disabled, then any previous Python installations *will be disabled*, but simply uninstalling the Anaconda/Miniconda installation should restore the original Python installation, except maybe the Windows Registry `Python\PythonCore` keys.

     Anaconda/Miniconda makes the following registry edits regardless of the installation options: `HKCU\Software\Python\ContinuumAnalytics\` with the following keys: `Help`, `InstallPath`, `Modules` and `PythonPath` - official Python registers these keys too, but under `Python\PythonCore`. Also uninstallation info is registered for Anaconda\Miniconda. Unless you select the "Register with Windows" option during installation, it doesn't create `PythonCore`, so integrations like Python Tools for Visual Studio do not automatically see Anaconda/Miniconda. If the option to register Anaconda/Miniconda *is* enabled, then I think your existing Python Windows Registry keys will be altered and uninstallation will probably not restore them.
   - [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) updates, I think, can be handled through the [WinPython  Control Panel](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/wiki/Winpython-Control-Panel).
   - [PortablePython](http://portablepython.com/) is **no longer being developed**. <s>It had no update method. Possibly updates could be unzipped into a fresh directory and then `App\lib\site-packages` and `App\Scripts` could be copied to the new installation, but if this didn't work then reinstalling all packages might have been necessary. Use `pip list` to see what packages were installed and their versions. Some were installed by PortablePython. Use `easy_install pip` to install pip if it wasn't installed.</s>
2. If OP has 2.7.x and wants to install a different version, *e.g.* <=2.6.x or >=3.x.x, then installing different versions side-by-side is fine. You must choose which version of Python (if any) to associate with `*.py` files and which you want on your path, although you should be able to set up shells with different paths if you use [BASH](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html). AFAIK 2.7.x is backwards compatible with 2.6.x, so IMHO side-by-side installs is not necessary, however Python-3.x.x is not backwards compatible, so my recommendation would be to put Python-2.7 on your path and have Python-3 be an optional version by creating a shortcut to its executable called python3 (this is a common setup on Linux). The official Python default install path on Windows is

   - C:\Python33 for 3.3.x (latest 2013-07-29)
   - C:\Python32 for 3.2.x
   - &c.
   - C:\Python27 for 2.7.x (latest 2013-07-29)
   - C:\Python26 for 2.6.x
   - &c.
3. If OP is not updating Python, but merely updating packages, they may wish to look into [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to keep the different versions of packages specific to their development projects separate. [Pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is also a great tool to update packages. If packages use binary installers I usually uninstall the old package before installing the new one.

I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Hey Mark, I have a newbie question. Do you believe it is actually important to upgrade from 2.7.x to 3.3.x?  I am starting to use python and have the old version installed, but since I'm beginning I wanted to learn the newest version (unless there are only very minor differences). What is your call on this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would use both. If you are on MS Windows, you will get in your root folder `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python33`, if you're on Mac, you'll see `/Library/Frameworks/Python/Versions/2.7.x` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python/Versions/3.3.x` and if you're on Linux you probably already have both install. Tradition is to use Python-2.7 and symlink the binary for Python-3.3 to `python33`. Also see [Python2orPython3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) and [Python 2 vs Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442352/python-2-vs-python-3-and-tutorial). I'm personally too lazy to switch to 3.3.

Comment: [Here's a post on Python 2 vs 3 for scientists](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/01/03/will-scientists-ever-move-to-python-3/)

Comment: "just install over old" is not proving to be easy on Windows -- the installer doesn't detect my old Python, appears to want to install a brand new IDLE, and fails with error 2349.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  With 2.7, installing over old didn't work when one was 32 bit and one was 64 bit.  I wound up with two entries in "Programs and Features", both pointing to C:\Python27.  Would you be willing to add to your answer that folks should only overwrite 32 with 32 and 64 with 64?  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw thanks for the feedback. If you do want to have both 32 and 64 together, there are ways. Probably the easiest is to use what's called an ["admin" install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541.aspx) of the 32-bit version into `C:\Python27_x86` from the command line: `msiexec /a "python-2.7.11.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Python27_x86" /qn /l*v python27_x86_install.log`. Another option is to [build from source](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2015/03/building-python-x64-on-windows-7-with.html), or try [Bootstrap Python](http://breakingbytes.bitbucket.org/).

Comment: MSI installer says that it will replace the 2.7 folder, however, if you store other scrips in the 2.7 root folder it will not delete them ;)

Comment: @XXN Thanks for that correction. Can you confirm that the `\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages` folder should also be preserved after an update on Windows from official [www,python.org](https://www.python.org/)? That is, your pip installed system packages should **not** be deleted. After an update, I believe you should be able to execute `py -m pip list` and see the same packages you had before the update.

Comment: @MarkMikofski yes, the packages installed previously also were preserved. I confirm this for the [2.7.15](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.msi) installer (I upgraded My Python from 2.7.6 to 2.7.15)

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to install the different Python versions in multiple paths.

eg. C:\Python27 for 2.7, and C:\Python33 for 3.3.

Read this for more info: [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows)

Comment: This is how I do it.
I run both 32 and 64 bit versions of python 2.7.xx and 3.5.xx and IronPython 2.7.xx.
I use Eclipse for development and choose the python path when debugging.
When running a script, I simply set the path to the interpreter version I wish to use.

Updating 3.5.0 to 3.5.3 offers a simple update option verses a new install.

Answer (score 5):

- Official Python .msi installers are designed to replace:

  - any previous micro release (in *x.y.z*, *z* is "micro") because they are guaranteed to be backward-compatible and binary-compatible
  - a "snapshot" (built from source) installation with any micro version
- A snapshot installer is designed to replace any snapshot with a lower micro version.

(See [responsible code for 2.x](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Tools/msi/msi.py#L274), [for 3.x](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/msi/msi.props#L82))

Any other versions are not necessarily compatible and are thus installed alongside the existing one. If you wish to uninstall the old version, you'll need to do that manually. And also uninstall any 3rd-party modules you had for it:

- If you installed any modules from `bdist_wininst` packages (Windows `.exe`s), uninstall them before uninstalling the version, or the uninstaller might not work correctly if it has custom logic
- modules installed with `setuptools`/`pip` that reside in `Lib\site-packages` can just be deleted afterwards
- packages that you installed per-user, if any, reside in `%APPDATA%/Python/PythonXY/site-packages` and can likewise be deleted

Answer (score 1):

I have always just installed the new version on top and never had any issues. Do make sure that your path is updated to point to the new version though.

Comment: When you install over top, does it retain the external modules like pygame, bs4, lxml, etc. which I downloaded?