# Change python3 executable to another version

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, ubuntu

Currently when I enter python3. It runs "python3.2.3" version but what I want is when I enter python3 on the shell is it should run "python3.5.1".

I am running on a Debian Wheezy OS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102943/how-to-update-python)

Comment: The instruction there is not clear besides it is on windows OS. I have a Debian Wheezy OS

Comment: Which OS are you running? Which environment? Maybe provide a little more details? Otherwise your question reads as "How do I do a thing?"

Answer (score 2):

I would say you need to look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This is a common tool for having isolated Python environments.

I won't provide here an example as simple Google search for "use multiple versions of Python" provides enough detailed material.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS/redhat you can just link /usr/bin/python to you "python3.2.3" executable.

RPM package just duplicates this binary:

```
[~]# md5sum /usr/bin/python2.6
71494aa9082392bff9f93b725773ec39  /usr/bin/python2.6
[~]# md5sum /usr/bin/python
71494aa9082392bff9f93b725773ec39  /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this help [Install python 3.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/install-python-3-5-on-vivid-using-apt-get), or you can also use [ANACONDA](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)