# How do I upgrade the Python installation in Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python 2.7.11 installed on one of my LAB stations. I would like to upgrade Python to at least 3.5.

How should I do that ?
Should I prefer to completely uninstall 2.7.11 and than install the new one ?
Is there a way to update it ? Is an update a good idea ?

Comment: Maybe this older post can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102943/how-to-update-python Br.

Comment: python2 and python3 should be treated as different langauges, like C# is different to C++

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Every minor version of Python, that is any 3.x and 2.x version, will install side-by-side with other versions on your computer. Only patch versions will upgrade existing installations.

So if you want to keep your installed Python 2.7 around, then just let it and install a new version using the installer. If you want to get rid of Python 2.7, you can uninstall it before or after installing a newer version—there is no difference to this.

Current Python 3 installations come with the `py.exe` launcher, which by default is installed into the system directory. This makes it available from the PATH, so you can automatically run it from any shell just by using `py` instead of `python` as the command. This avoids you having to put the current Python installation into PATH yourself. That way, you can easily have multiple Python installations side-by-side without them interfering with each other. When running, just use `py script.py` instead of `python script.py` to use the launcher. You can also specify a version using for example `py -3` or `py -3.6` to launch a specific version, otherwise the launcher will use the current default (which will usually be the latest 3.x).

Using the launcher, you can also run Python 2 scripts (which are often syntax incompatible to Python 3), if you decide to keep your Python 2.7 installation. Just use `py -2 script.py` to launch a script.

---

As for PyPI packages, every Python installation comes with its own folder where modules are installed into. So if you install a new version and you want to use modules you installed for a previous version, you will have to install them first for the new version. Current versions of the installer also offer you to install `pip`; it’s enabled by default, so you already have `pip` for every installation. Unless you explicitly add a Python installation to the PATH, you cannot just use `pip` though. Luckily, you can also simply use the `py.exe` launcher for this: `py -m pip` runs `pip`. So for example to install Beautiful Soup for Python 3.6, you could run `py -3.6 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: How would you recommend to do that on a station that I am currently using for development of scripts ? By the way, I have a 3.5.2 (Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: Just install the new version side-by-side. There’s no need to remove the old version. Having the old version might even help you to migrate existing scripts from Python 2 to Python 3, so you can still run the original ones.

Comment: Besides of updating the PATH, with the new installation, I will also need to update the IDE that I am working with. Right ?

Comment: The installer will give you an option to set the PATH for you, so you might not need to do that manually. And yeah, your IDE needs to be updated.

Comment: also `py -3.7-64` or `py -3.7-32`

Comment: **Note:** `py` is the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher). Or see [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) that defines it. It doesn't get installed for Linux/Mac.

Comment: I just attempted an upgrade from 3.8 to 3.9 (Win 10).  I was not offered the upgrade option.  I will manually uninstall 3.8.  Could it be that this is influenced by PyCharm.

Comment: @chribonn That is expected behavior. The different minor versions (e.g. 3.9, 3.8, 3.7) can all be installed side-by-side and will not replace each other. It’s only when you update to a newer version within that minor version that you will get an upgrade. If you don’t need 3.8 any more, then it’s perfectly safe to uninstall it and install 3.9 instead.

Answer (score 137):

If you are upgrading any 3.x.y to 3.x.z (patch) Python version, just go to [Python downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) get the latest version and start the installation. Since you already have Python installed on your machine installer will prompt you for "Upgrade Now". Click on that button and it will replace the existing version with a new one. You also will have to restart a computer after installation.

[image]

If you are upgrading from 3.x to 3.y (minor) then you will be prompted with "Install Now". In this case, you are not upgrading, but you are installing a new version of Python. You can have more than one version installed on your machine. They will be located in different directories. When you have more than one Python version on your machine you will need to use [py lanucher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) to launch a specific version of Python.

For instance:

> py -3.7

or

> py -3.8

Make sure you have [py launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) installed on your machine. It will be installed automatically if you are using default settings of windows installer. You can always check it if you click on "Customize installation" link on the installation window.

If you have several Python versions installed on your machine and you have a project that is using the previous version of Python using virtual environment e.g. (venv) you can upgrade Python just in that venv using:

> python -m venv --upgrade "your virtual environment path"

For instance, I have Python 3.7 in my ./venv virtual environment and I would like upgrade venv to Python 3.8, I would do following

> python -m venv --upgrade ./venv

Comment: I will try that ASAP. By doing it so I can migrate from version 3.5 for example to 3.7 ? What about all the pip list ? I assume that I will need to upgrade some or all of its contents, right ?

Comment: @MosheS.you can get a list of outdated packages using the following command:

pip list --outdated

and then update each package by

python -m pip install --upgrade <your package>

Comment: Moving from 3.7.2 to 3.7.4 (64 bit) on Windows 10 I do not see this, I see "Install Now" where you see "Upgrade Now"

Comment: I just moved from 3.7.3 to 3.7.5 and got the "Upgrade Now" message. If I tried to upgrade from 3.7.3 to 3.8 then I would get "Install Now".

Comment: Doesn't work. I had Python 3.7.4 and when I run 3.8.1 installer I had no choice "Upgrade now", only "Install"

Comment: @Suncatcher you are right, that is what I described "If you would like to upgrade from 3.x to 3.y then ... " section. Please read the above.

Comment: `If you are upgrading any 3.x Python version` so this part is true only when upgrading from 2.7 to 3.x? If so, it is needed to be stated explicitly, it's not clear from the context

Comment: When going 3.x.y to 3.z.w I also updated my system PATH, removing old versions and making sure the new version was there.  I don't know if this was necessary, but it didn't seem to be automatic.

Answer (score 66):

## Installing/Upgrading Python Using the Chocolatey Windows Package Manager

Let's say you have Python 2.7.16:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python --version
python2 2.7.16
```

...and you want to upgrade to the (now current) 3.x.y version.  There is a simple way to install a *parallel* installation of Python 3.x.y using a Windows package management tool.

Now that modern Windows has package management, just like Debian Linux distributions have apt-get, and RedHat has dnf: we can put it to work for us! It's called **Chocolatey**.

### What's Chocolatey?

Chocolatey is a scriptable, command line tool that is based on .NET 4.0 and the nuget package manager baked into Visual Studio.

If you want to learn about Chocolatey and why to use it, which some here reading this might find particularly useful, go to https://chocolatey.org/docs/why

### Installing Chocolatey

To get the Chocolatey Package Manager, you follow a process that is described at https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#installing-chocolatey,

I'll summarize it for you here.  There are basically two options: using the cmd prompt, or using the PowerShell prompt.

#### CMD Prompt Chocolatey Installation

Launch an *administrative* command prompt.  On Windows 10, to do this:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type *cmd*
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>

If you don't have administrator rights on the system, go to the [Chocolatey website](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#installing-chocolatey).  You may not be completely out of luck and can perform a limited local install, but I won't cover that here.

- Copy the string below into your command prompt and type Enter:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Chocolatey will be downloaded and installed for you as below:

```
Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
Getting Chocolatey from https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.10.11.
Downloading 7-Zip commandline tool prior to extraction.
Extracting C:\Users\blahblahblah\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\blahblahblah\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall...
Installing chocolatey on this machine
Creating ChocolateyInstall as an environment variable (targeting 'Machine')
  Setting ChocolateyInstall to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'
WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
  before you can use choco.
Restricting write permissions to Administrators
We are setting up the Chocolatey package repository.
The packages themselves go to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib'
  (i.e. C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName).
A shim file for the command line goes to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin'
  and points to an executable in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName'.

Creating Chocolatey folders if they do not already exist.

WARNING: You can safely ignore errors related to missing log files when
  upgrading from a version of Chocolatey less than 0.9.9.
  'Batch file could not be found' is also safe to ignore.
  'The system cannot find the file specified' - also safe.
chocolatey.nupkg file not installed in lib.
 Attempting to locate it from bootstrapper.
PATH environment variable does not have C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin in it. Adding...
WARNING: Not setting tab completion: Profile file does not exist at 'C:\Users\blahblahblah\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.
Chocolatey (choco.exe) is now ready.
You can call choco from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing choco.
Run choco /? for a list of functions.
You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles
 first prior to using choco.
Ensuring chocolatey commands are on the path
Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder
```

Either *Exit* the CMD prompt or type the following command to reload the environment variables:

```
refreshenv
```

#### PowerShell Chocolatey Installation

If you prefer PowerShell to the cmd prompt, you can do this directly from there, however you will have to tell PowerShell to run with a proper script execution policy to get it to work.  On Windows 10, the simplest way I have found to do this is to type the following into the Cortana search bar next to the Windows button:

```
PowerShell.exe
```

Next, right click on the 'Best Match' choice in the menu that pops up and select 'Run as Administrator'

Now that you're in PowerShell, hopefully running with Administrator privileges, execute the following to install Chocolatey:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

PowerShell will download Chocolatey for you and launch the installation.  It only takes a few moments.  It looks *exactly* like the CMD installation, save perhaps some fancy colored text.

Either *Exit* PowerShell or type the following command to reload the environment variables:

```
refreshenv
```

### Upgrading Python

The choco command is the same whether you use PowerShell or the cmd prompt.  Launch your favorite using the instructions as above.  I'll use the administrator cmd prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco upgrade python -y
```

Essentially, chocolatey will tell you "Hey, Python isn't installed" since you're coming from 2.7.x and it treats the 2.7 version as *completely* separate. It is *only* going to give you the most current version, 3.x.y (as of this writing, 3.7.2, but that will change in a few months):

```
Chocolatey v0.10.11
Upgrading the following packages:
python
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
python is not installed. Installing...

python3 v3.x.y [Approved]
python3 package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing 64-bit python3...
python3 has been installed.
Installed to: 'C:\Python37' 
  python3 can be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The upgrade of python3 was successful.
  Software installed as 'exe', install location is likely default.

python v3.x.y [Approved]
python package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
 The upgrade of python was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey upgraded 2/2 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

*Either* exit out of the cmd/Powershell prompt and re-enter it, or use refreshenv then type py --version

```
C:\Windows\System32>refreshenv
Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait...Finished..

C:\Windows\system32>py --version
Python 3.7.2
```

Note that the most recent Python install will now take over when you type Python at the command line.  You can run either version by using the following commands:

```
py -2
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

C:\>py -3
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>exit()
C:\>
```

From here I suggest you use the Python *pip* utility to install whatever packages you need.  For example, let's say you wanted to install Flask.  The commands below first upgrade pip, then install Flask

```
C:\>py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 1.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
    Uninstalling pip-18.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3

c:\>py -3 -m pip install Flask
```

...will do the trick.  Happy Pythoning!

Comment: The short version of the answer is install Chocolatey and then refreshenv from your command prompt then perform choco install python it will install the latest version of python. Do refreshenv again in the cmd and you should be running the latest python from your cmd.

Comment: Getting this error in CMD and POWERSHELL

Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
At line:1 char:104
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString <<<< ('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 8):

A quick and painless way for me was to do the following:

1. Do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on my affected environments (or whatever method you want for backing up your requirements)
2. Remove the Old version of Python (in my case it was 3.8)
3. Remove the associated environments
4. Install the new version (3.9.5 in my case)
5. Recreate my environments `python -m venv venv` or however you wish
6. Reinstall my plug-ins/apps `pip install -r requirements.txt` or however you wish

Comment: ...this is best for only 1 version.

Comment: even though this is the best way, it is still quite clunky (5 steps) with installs and uninstalls...  is there a quicker way to achieve the same ?

Comment: You could get away with leaving the old version installed i suppose and just do the new environment and reinstall your requirements but might get confusing with different versions installed.

Answer (score 5):

In 2019, you can install using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Open your cmd or powershell, type:

```
choco install python
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you can just install several Python versions from Microsoft Store. Those are published there by Python Software Foundation.

[image: Python versions availble in Microsoft Store]

https://apps.microsoft.com/store/search?hl=en-en&gl=EN&publisher=Python%20Software%20Foundation

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.x and Python 3.x are different. If you would like to download a newer version of Python 2, you could just download and install the newer version.

If you want to install Python 3, you could install Python 3 separately then change the path for Python 2.x to Python 3.x in Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: I prefer to completely remove Python 2.7.11 as I don't plan on supporting it. So I should completely remove it. Right ? The "Programs and Features" didn't show Python so I don't know how to remove it. Should I use pip, and how ? Is it a good idea to just Delete the Python folder ? What about all the old packages that were installed with it (if there were any), how can I uninstall them too ?

Comment: @MosheS. I don't think it really takes that much space, but if you do want to clean up then by all means.

They should all be in the same folder, you can probably uninstall from control panel Program and Features. Both my Python 2.7 and 3.4 are in there. Uninstalling from there will remove all packages

If you really cannot find it you can try just deleting the whole folder. When you download Python 3 and if it doesn't work, go edit the path as I answered above, that would most probably be the main issue, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Just install python newest version's installer it will automatically detect your python version and will say upgrade python and starts upgrading

Comment: this is only true for micro versions `major.minor.micro` so `3.x.y` to 3.x.z` would be the case,  but if you were upgrading a minor version then it will install a new version side by side to the existing version...  so `3.a.x` to `3.b.x` would leave two versions `3a` and `3b`...

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). It let you easily switch between all versions of python.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider giving more detains on your answers

Answer (score -1):

I was able to execute PowerShell with the following command and python upgraded with no issue.  python -m pip install --upgrade pip please see image

Comment: Please format your answer properly. 
Also, I see that you forgot to add an image to your answer. Please add the image and proof of work if possible and it might help answer much better.

Comment: This only upgrades pip and not python.