# Using latest Python version

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pyenv

I am setting up a new computer and the current latest version of Python is Python 3.4.6. I am trying to update it to version 3.7.0 (the latest version at the time of writing).

I tried `pyenv install 3.7.0` and it successfully installed.

But when I type `$ python3 --version` at the command line it still says Python 3.4.6.

When I type `$ which python3` the path it shows is `/.pyenv/shims/python3`.
Navigating to that path I find that there also exists `/.pyenv/shims/python3.7`.

How do I point the `python` command to the newest install?

I know there are a million questions asking how to point `python` from Python 2.x to Python 3.x. But I have not found one showing how to point from Python 3.old to Python 3.new

I am using Linux OpenSuse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade the Python installation in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137395/how-do-i-upgrade-the-python-installation-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `pyenv global` command.  In this case, it should be `pyenv global 3.7.0`.  Check out the [pyenv commands list](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md) for more info.