# Requested runtime (Python-3.7.3) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)

Tags: python, django, heroku, runtime-error

I'm using Django 2.2.3 and I'm getting this error:

```
Requested runtime (Python-3.7.3) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)
```

But, [Heroku's Python documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) says that `python-3.7.3` should be available in stack `heroku-18`.

`runtime.txt` contains `Python-3.7.3`.

**FULL ERROR**

```
Counting objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 10.70 KiB | 996.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 43 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python-3.7.3) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like just about everything else in the Heroku ecosystem, `runtime.txt` is case-sensitive. Change its contents to

```
python-3.7.3
```

with a lowercase `p`.

Answer (score 3):

I found my self into this error using Windows10 and trying to push my project into Heroku. Mine is a Flask app.

**ERROR:**

> Requested runtime (Python-3.7.1) is not available for this stack
>   (heroku-18)

**What happened?**
I did have Python 3.7.1 installed on my machine.
Even when declaring python-3.7.2 into runtime.txt I had the error.

**What I did?**
Checked my python version via powershell (as admin): python --version
Was 3.7.1

Then upgraded the python via chocolatey. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069640/8382762).

1. choco upgrade python -y
2. refreshenv
3. Close and reopen your code editor OR reboot the system.

Checked my python version one more time: now I have 3.8.0, which is a supported stack.

I did go back to my project and deleted the virtualenv folder (mine was venv).
Started over the venv creation, dependencies installation, and setup.

Add python-3.8.0 into runtime.txt and retry the whole heroku deployment.

**VOILÁ!**

*Note: remember to update your environment variables and python Path.*

*Note 2: Please let us know your results or solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

I think this stack of heroku is not compatible with this python version, try upgarding your stack using this command:
**heroku stack:set heroku-20**
or try some other stack from this [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack)

Answer (score 0):

I had to select from the supported Python versions listed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how it will help you. I just removed the requirements.txt file from my django app then heroku automatically detected the python version and now it works fine

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution. To start, the `requirements.txt` is there for a reason- to specify the exact versions necessary to run the project. Removing them could mess up other things along the way.