# Upgrade Python in Windows

Tags: python

I have Python 3.8.0 and I want to know how could I upgrade it to version 3.8.1 without download and reinstallation.

I upgraded all my installed extensions with this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade EXTENSION_NAME
```

But the version of Python still 3.8.0

Comment: This isn't possible without downloading and installing. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137395/how-do-i-upgrade-the-python-installation-in-windows-10

Comment: If you already have Python 3.8.0 installed, you probably don't need to reinstall all your extensions. Just download the Python installer and run it. It will just upgrade the Python interpreter and the standard libraries that come with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137395/how-do-i-upgrade-the-python-installation-in-windows-10 follow this link.

Comment: @PeterWood I thought if the version is "major.minor.micro" so I can upgrade the "micro" version without taking care of braking old Python's scripts that stored on the machine when they will running in the future.

Comment: Okay, thank you all, I got it. I will reinstall to upgrade my version of Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade the Python installation in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137395/how-do-i-upgrade-the-python-installation-in-windows-10)