# error while updating Python from the tar.gz file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

I want to upgrade my python3.7.9, I ran .tgz file of both 3.7.12 and 3.7.13 both are giving the same error

[image]

Comment: Please post what you are tying to do and the error as text rather than a image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade the Python installation in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137395/how-do-i-upgrade-the-python-installation-in-windows-10)

Comment: I am trying to upgrade my python installation it does not have a installer so I have to use the tgz file

Answer (score -1):

u cant install python with pip
extract the tgz file
and go to the directory (cd)

then type python setup.py install --user

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    set_compiler_flags('CFLAGS', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
  File "setup.py", line 27, in set_compiler_flags
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()[compiler_flags] = flags + ' ' + py_flags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: still getting same error