# Unable to import tensorflow in python: "no module named tools"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm fairly new to tensorflow, and I set it up using pip. After it installed, I ran `python -c "import tensorflow"`, and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ImportError: No module named tools
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this later: I just had to run it with `python3` instead of `python`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue but first of all what I will say is this:

- check your version of python by using:

  `$ python --version`
- If you are using a version of that is python 2.7.x or lower, know that it is deprecated as of Jan 2020. You can upgrade you version to python 3.6 or higher by using the following post -  [How to update Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102943/how-to-update-python).

If you want to use a version of python 2.7.x or lower for any reason or if you are using a version of Python 3 or higher. You want to update the TensorFlow package this can be done by using:

`$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

If it is already up to date try reinstalling the TensorFlow package by using:

`$ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue with TF2.1 x Python2.7. Solved it by installing functools32 which is listed as required dependency in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L74):

> # functools comes with python3, need to install the backport for python2
>   'functools32 >= 3.2.3;python_version<"3"',

Comment: Thanks, I solved the same problem by installing functools32 and opt_einsum from the required dependency list for python2.7.