# Starting different python versions from the command line

Tags: python, windows, path, installation

The setup: Win7 environment with Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2 installed and added to the system path.

```
C:\\py -2
```

will launch Python 2.7.5,

```
C:\\py -3
```

will launch Python 3.3.2,

```
C:\\python
```

will launch Python 3.3.2.

**Is it possible to toggle which Python version "python" maps to, and if so, how?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last line, Windows picks the first directory on your `%PATH%` containing a `python` executable.  You cannot change that, short of reordering your path.

I use this little `py.bat` file in a directory early in my path:

```
\python27\python.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

So I just type `py`.  I have a similar `py3.bat` to start Python 3 instead.  Inside other `.bat` files I call `py.bat` or `py3.bat`, so they all pick up the version of Python I want when I change `py.bat` and/or `py3.bat`.

Edit:  by the way, I realize my `py.bat`'s name conflicts with the Python launcher named `py`.  I don't care :-)

Comment: That would explain it. So that I'm clear on your setup- you have created .bat files (we'll say "pythonX.bat" to avoid the conflict), and have added them to your system path, so that each of them starts the corresponding version of Python?

Comment: Yup, that's it.  I have `py.bat` (call it `py2.bat` if you like - doesn't matter) for Python 2 and `py3.bat` for Python 3.  I also have many others, because I'm a Python developer, and sometimes need to access old versions (like, e.g., `py274.bat` for Python 2.7.4).  BTW, on recent enough Windows versions you can use `%*` in the `.bat` files instead of the long-winded `%1 %2 ... %9`.

Comment: I was going to ask you about the sequence of numbers- what does that accomplish?

Comment: Batch files have arguments.  `%1` is the first argument, `%2` the second argument, and so on.  So when I run, e.g., `py -i`, the first argument is `-i`, and the batch file passes `%1 %2 ... %9` to Python so that *Python* sees the same arguments.  That is `py -i` ends up running `\python27\python.exe -i`.