# Django is installing to the wrong python version

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I had python 2.6 and I downloaded Django. I found that python 2.6 throws errors when trying to run django, so I downloaded python 2.7. Now, typing python in the terminal runs 2.7 but the django library isn't in the 2.7 folder. So I uninstalled django using:

```
sudo pip uninstall django
```

and that worked just fine. When i used the command:

```
sudo pip install django
```

it installed into the python 2.6 instead of python 2.7.

How can I install django into python 2.7 instead of python 2.6?

(I am running a MacBook Pro on 1.6, and I was told to not uninstall the base version of python because so many of the systems use 2.6)

Comment: Mac can be a pain, you will have to change the default version it uses. However, forget all that and use virtualenv! It will save your life. Virtualenv creates a Python environment that is segregated from your system wide Python installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `pip` for python2.7. If it's installed, you should be able to see it using `which pip-2.7`.

It's better not to touch system python. Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install your own.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running *pip* from your default *Python* installation (2.6), read this: [How to run multiple python version on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4583367/2343488), maybe answers give you how to solve in your *OS X*.

You can view the version of your default *Python* installation by executing `python -V`, there is a way to specify which version to use when you execute `python`, in *Linux* you can create an alias (`alias python=python2.7`) in your `$HOME/.bash_profile`, *OS X* must have something similar, then install *pip* using your preferred version.

BTW, It's recommended to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)