# Installing multiple python versions on windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I installed python 3.4 and python 3.5 to `C:\Python34` and `C:\Python35` respectively.
and I created two bat files refering to these executables namely `python.bat` and `python35.bat` and added them to my `PATH`. so that I can get

```
C:\>python -V 
Python 3.4.3

C:\>python35 -V
Python 3.5.1

C:\>pip
```

This works fine for me, except when I want to call `PIP` because it is actually inside the `PythonXX\Scripts\` folder.

Is there an easy way to get away with calling pip and other scripts from cmd,
without typing `C:\>Python34\Scripts\pip` or `C:\>Python35\Scripts\pip` each time?

(Note: pip is not the only file I want to run from Scripts folder. can I do the alias for the Scripts directory?)

Comment: couldn't you do the exact same thing than with the python executable?

Comment: Do something like `set PATH=C:\Python35\Scripts;%PATH%` in your bat file

Comment: @J.J.Hakala would that be a permanent change or for a single session only? (If it's permanent, you would be updating `PATH` for each time you load the bat file

Comment: @Zetys I was hoping to find a solution on the directory level, so that I dont need to rename all executables inside Scripts (pip and others)

Comment: FWIW, I have a `pip2.7.exe` in my `c:\Python\Scripts` and a `pip3.5.exe` in my `c:\Python3\Scripts` folder so I can be explicit about which one I want at the command line.

Comment: see [_Permanent Windows command-line aliases with doskey and AutoRun_](http://darkforge.blogspot.com/2010/08/permanent-windows-command-line-aliases.html) to learn how to make your aliases load automatically.

Comment: Use the py.exe launcher that installs in `%SystemRoot%`? For example, `py -3.4 -m pip` and `py -3.5 -m pip`. Nothing in `PATH`.  No batch files. No configuration. Use shebangs in your scripts such as `#!python3.5` and `#!python3` (latest). Double-click on or run .py scripts directly. py.exe also recognizes an active `venv` virtual environment, but in that case `python` and `pip` work just as well. The only thing you may want to configure is adding `.PY` to `PATHEXT` to run scripts without have to type the .py extension.

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can create [symbolic links](https://serverfault.com/questions/7109/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-windows):

```
for %A in (c:\Python34\Scripts\*.exe) do mklink C:\Windows\System32\%~nA34.exe %A
```

Then call `pip` with `pip34`.
Do the same thing with other python versions.

Comment: is there a way to make an alias for the Scripts directory, so it works for all executables inside it?

Comment: not exactly what i was hoping for as it still alias the .exe files not the directory. (for example won`t work if .exe is in sub directory of Scripts). still useful though. thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

You could set up some aliases

```
doskey pip34=C:\python34\scripts\pip
doskey pip35=C:\python35\scripts\pip
```

I don't have a windows shell to test this on, but from what I've read it "should" work.

Comment: There are multiple files inside scripts. so I am searching for a solution for the whole directory. I have updated the question to clarify this point