# How to upgrade from Python 3.5 to 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6

My machine runs on Windows and I tried to find out about it but people only talk about mac and `brew` on other discussions. I want to ask if there is  a command line which I need to write which can upgrade the core or I have to download 3.6 package from the official website and then uninstall the 3.5 and then install 3.6 (and I don't want to do that because it sounds mess to me)

I have `3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]`

Any help?

Comment: You can select your interpreter explicitly - `C:\Python36\python.exe my_file.py`. Or you can use unified Windows runner: `py -3.6 my_file.py` for 3.6, `py -3.5 my_file.py` for 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to download Python 3.6 package, but no need to uninstall the 3.5 Version (you can have both)

Keep in mind that the custom libraries you where using with python 3.5 have to be installed for 3.6 too, but you can do that with pip easily

Changing the interpreter from pycharm can be achieved when creating a new project:

[image]

or from default settings for an already created project:

[image]

Comment: but how can i run my scripts in 3.5 then? because when i do .. print(sys.version) it says 3.5

Comment: if you are running you script from cmd line, you will specify the path for the python 3.6 like this: C:/users/me/python36/python.exe myscript.py

Comment: so actually the question is how you are running your script? from Python IDLE, cmd, visual studio, pycharm?

Comment: for example I run my code from VS, if I wan't to change from 3.5 to 3.6 (having installed both), I have to add a new Environment for python 3.6

Comment: But if you are running from the Basic python IDLE, then you should have one both for 3.5 and 3.6

Comment: any ideas for pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

On Unix it would be fair enough to correct softlinks. On Windows as far as I see people resort to playing around with paths. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows) is the most detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

If someone's using MacOS, Linux or WSL then can use [asdf](http://asdf-vm.com/).

1. Clone the **asdf** repository

```
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.8.1
```

2. Edit `~/.bashrc` file and add `$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh`
3. Restart your terminal and you'll be able to use **asdf**
4. In order to add the plugins, in your case **Python**, you can run this -

```
asdf plugin add python
```

5. List all the versions of python -

```
asdf list all python
```

6. Install the version as per your requirement (can install the latest one) -

```
asdf install python latest
```

7. Set the installed version **globally**, **locally** (for a particular project) or for this particular **shell** .

```
asdf global python latest
```