# Python 3 Get inputs when runing scripts in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Hello All I am in the process of making a script that requires input form the user to be passed to my code i.e enter the file path. it all works well with in python but if I run my script from windows(cmd) each time the input is entered the script crashes with syntax error.

```
import os 

search_path = input("Enter directory path to search : ")

for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):

      blah, blah
```

Anyone got any clues to what i am missing (note: using `Python 3.6`)

Comment: I assume you're running `python script.py`. What's printed for `python --version`, and what's the printed path for `where python`?

Comment: python --version give the response of Python 3.6. but it seems there was two version of python installed (2.7) and my Windows environment path was set for version 2.7 to seem i install 3.6 then uninstall 2.7 and did not update my environment path. now it all works thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also have windows and python 3.6 
i have tried your code above and worked fine for me

```
import os
sp=input('enter directory path to search: \n')
for folder,dirs,files in os.walk(sp):
    print('sss')
```

i think you have 2 different version of python installed alongside.
check the version from cmd type

```
python --version
```

and if it shows 2.x then try from python3 
look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1)
for running multiple version of python

Comment: python --version give the response of Python 3.6. but it seems there was two version of python installed (2.7) and my Windows environment path was set for version 2.7 to seem i install 3.6 then uninstall 2.7 and did not update my environment path. now it all works thanks very much for your help :)