# Netgen.exe - System Error python35.dll was not found

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation

I installed Python 3.6.3 64bit through Anaconda on my 64bit Win10. And I installed Netgen 64bit from [the official sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netgen-mesher/). But when I try to run Negen I get the error:

> The code execution cannot proceed because python35.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this issue.

[image]

1. I tried reinstalling but it did not help
2. I checked I have installed everything in 64bit and my python is also 64
3. I'm pretty sure my python is added to the PATH, when I run python in the command line it opens the python shell.
4. there are similar posts suggesting to download the missing .dll from the internet. I don't think that's such a good idea.

I would appreciate if you could help me know  what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: Which *specific* Python 3.x release did you install?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 3.6.3 also added to the OP

Comment: There's your problem -- your Netgen installer is built for Python 3.5, you installed Python 3.6. You either need a newer build of Netgen (if one doesn't exist, to run one yourself), or to use an older Python.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so what should do? should I downgrade my python? any other workaround?

Comment: No other workaround, no -- only point releases, not minor releases, are binary-compatible. You can downgrade your Python, you can look for a newer Netgen build, you can -- potentially, given the source and an appropriate build toolchain -- run a newer build yourself.

Comment: Mind you, you can have Python 3.5 and 3.6 both installed at the same time, so "downgrade" isn't necessarily mandatory as such.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I build the netgen source with a newer version of python maybe you can give me the instructions? installing both pythons is also possible. I guess I have to remove newer python from PATH and then install the older one and add it to the path?

Comment: No, you don't need to remove the new one from the PATH. And instructions for compiling 3rd-party software are a bit out-of-scope here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so you say it is theoretically possible to build Netgen with newer python, given the source code?

Comment: Correct, it is theoretically possible to build Netgen with newer Python, given the source code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where is the proper place to ask for build instructions?

Comment: The mailing list for the Netgen project, if they don't already have documentation in the source tree (and if they aren't already compatible with the standardized setuptools/distutils-based compilation procedure).

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html re: said standardized procedure, if they *do* have a `setup.py` that tries to support it. It's acceptable to ask questions here if you've tried to follow those steps and hit problems, not if you haven't tried yet.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I emailed the developers reported the issue. They don't have a mailing that I know of and the bug report in Sourceforge needs admin authorization! Thanks for your help. I appreciate your patience and kindness.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, if you do want to try compiling yourself, also see https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers describing which compiler versions you need to build native C modules for Python -- for Python 3.6, you'll need Visual Studio 14.0.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6.x does not provide `python35.dll`.

Install a Python 3.5 interpreter.

Comment: 1. which python 3.5.x should I install? 2. Does it mess up my original install? 3. should I remove the original install from PATH and add the 3.5.x?

Comment: 1. Any -- so typically the newest. 2. No. 3. You don't need to remove your original install; the installer should add the new one.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Latest Netgen releases are available from http://www.ngsolve.org
They use Python 3.6

Comment: it seems that the SourceFroge repo doesn't have the latest binary. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case netgen could not find python37.dll , and I had Python 3.9 . Eventually I renamed python39.dll to python37.dll, netgen called me names ("use of python37.dll conflicts with this version of Python"), but started to work.

Answer (score 0):

just edit environment variables to add `path` to `python37.dll` which is generally in `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I thought I would add the brute-force solution that worked.

The issue for me was that I cannot 'install' the older python 3.7, it messes with all my recent python 3.11 coding/work. I can't have it in my Path either.

So what I did:
I downloaded the python-3.7.9-embed-amd64.zip

and just unzipped all the files into the main Ngsolve \bin\ folder, such as:

C:\Program Files\ngsolve-v6.2.2301\bin\

Netgen then runs.
Brute force, but does work for anyone trying to get around the "python 3.7 dll not found" issue.

hope this is helpful.