# how can i run two versions of python 2.7.15 and 3.6.4 and How to install packages to specific version of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm using python 3.6.4 and 2.5.17 windows 10 and when I try to run any code, it only runs using version 2.7.15
I've tried  to add to the first line of my code:

```
#! python3
```

or

```
#! python2
```

and nothing happened 
and I also tried to use

`py -the number of versions`

i have this output:

`'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

and if I wanna download anything using `pip` or `pip3` command for python 3.6.4
it only installs it for python 2.7.15.
I've checked the environment variables I have python 2.7.15 and 3.6.4 included 
Can anyone one help me?

## edit:

i have the py launcher installed on my PC :

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s96q6.jpg)

and when i try to run it :

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBe5j.jpg)

and python files are included in the system variables

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvupn.jpg)

and the python 3.6.4 directory only contain thous files :

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6UqO.jpg)

> so what i have to do to run two versins of python now ?? and how to run scripts in atom ?

Comment: You either skipped the option to install the `py` launcher at install time, or you changed your environment variables in some way after doing so. If you just re-run the 3.6.4 installer, I believe it gives you the option to modify your existing installation instead of reinstalling. And if you then enable the option to install `py`, that should fix it.

Comment: first line should be like this #!/bin/env/python3 or #!/bin/env/python2.

Comment: This answer will get taken down because I am not answering your question completely and I do not have enough reputation to comment, but look into setting up a virtual machine to run different versions of python. I hope this can help you at least a little bit, good luck! [This may help](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/)

Comment: @user6924051 Not for Windows. You can optionally do that for cross-platform scripts, but for scripts meant to be run only on Windows via `py`, what the OP has written is exactly what’s recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows)

Comment: @abarnert actually i have the python launcher installed and i don't know what to do

Comment: The error message "'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command" means you don't have it installed, or at least it isn't on your PATH. If you do have it installed, you don't have a question.

Comment: @abarnert how can i add the launcher to my path ??

Comment: The installer should do that for you, unless you tell it not to. See [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) for details on what location it picks, how it stores that in the registry, etc.

Comment: @whoosis i've seen that question it was not helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about windows, but if you have installed **Anaconda prompt** for windows, then you can install different versions of python on Anaconda prompt and give them specific names. Like for me, I have python3.6.5 version named as `base` version and the python2.7 version as `py27`. Whenever I need to switch to either of them, I just use `activate` command:

`activate py27    //to switch to python2.7`

```
activate base    //to switch to python3.6.5
```

This automatically switches me to specified version of python in the anaconda prompt and then you can work it whichever way you like.