# Commands to run different python versions on venv at once CMD

Tags: python, cmd, virtual-machine, virtualhost, python-venv

I am currently running python 3.9 on my system. Due to the incompatibility of some of python libraries like numba on python 3.9 I will have to use previous versions. What cmd commands will I have to use to create a virtual environment so that I could run python 3.6 on cmd separate from python 3.9. I have a windows 10 64 bit system, I dont use conda or anything.

CMD Output:

```
C:\Users\maste>python -V
Python 3.9.1
```

Comment: Install `python3.6` using : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows 
Then create a `venv` using `python3.6` and activate that.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can utilize the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher). You can just install multiple Python versions from Python.org, and then use

```
py -3.6 -m venv venv
```

To create a virtual environment called "venv" (the last argument is the name). After that just activate your virtual environment and `python` will point to the Python 3.6 in your virtual environment.

Instead of the `py` launcher, you can also just use the full file path of the Python 3.6 (assuming Powershell, hence `&`):

```
& "C:\path\to\python 3.6\python.exe" -m venv venv
```

Lastly, you don't have to activate the virtual environment, if you don't want to. You can just run

```
<path-to-project>\venv\Scripts\python.exe myscript.py
```