# Computer started running Python version 2.7

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, version

When I turned on VSCode today I checked the Python version I was running and it told me 2.7. It was suppose to be 3.7. I checked to see if I was in a virtual environment and I wasn't. I checked my terminal and on my Mac and it said 3.7. So I don't know what is going on. I spent a few hours trying to fix it and got no success.

Also, I spent all day playing around it my computer to fix it and I don't know how, but now my Mac is running 2.7. I also downloaded 3.9 to see if that will fix it but it is still running 2.7. What should I do?

Comment: Any thing wrong with your PATH variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows)

Comment: Your example doesn't provide a MRE- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @treeson -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, we need to select a [Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) in VS Code, it will be displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code, and then, when we open the VS Code terminal(Shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+`), it will automatically enter this python environment:

[image]

When we do not select the python environment, the VS Code terminal will use the first python in the python environment variable by default:

[image]