# Python 3.10: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to **statsmodel**. I installed **statsmodel** using the `pip install statsmodels` in the CMD terminal.

However every time I try to run the   `import statsmodels.api as sm` in Spyder I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Do I have to add Spyder as into Windows Path to get access to the statsmodels library? Why is statsmodels not loading? Here is proof that I have it installed:

```
C:\Users\Jessica>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
numpy           1.21.4
pandas          1.3.4
patsy           0.5.2
pip             21.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2021.3
scipy           1.7.2
setuptools      57.4.0
six             1.16.0
statsmodels     0.13.0
```

Comment: Check if your global python version and project python version the same (Are you using virtual env or pyenv?)

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: run `python --version` from cmd and `import sys; print(sys.version)` inside Spyder. And check is it the same

Comment: My Python version is 'Python 3.10.0'. My System version is 3.7.9 (Aug. 17, 2020). So they are not the same. Should they be the same?

Comment: `Should they be the same?` → No. Correct question is: `Should I use specific pip for 3.10 if multiple pips (and pythons) installed on my OS` → Yes. Exact pip for exact python. Many pythons  == many pips. Learn how to manage multiple pythons on one OS. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows), [2](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-using-virtualenv/), [3](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-10-c90098d7ba5a)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run:

`python -m pip install statsmodels`