# Execution error when run symbolic link in cmd of Windows 11

Tags: python, command-prompt, symlink

After I create a symbolic link for `python.exe`, I can start up python when I double click the symbolic link. But when I enter the symbolic link into the command prompt, it tells me that `can not find python.dll`. So I have two questions as follows:

1. Is double click different from command prompt, why the former works fine but the later not?
2. How can I start up python by entering the symbolic link into the command prompt, without encountering `can not find python.dll`?

Some details that may help solve the problem:

- The operation system is Windows 11.
- The symbolic link is located in `E:\sybmolic\py.exe` while python is located in `E:\python\python.exe`.

Comment: python.exe looks for python.dll in the same folder, so if python.exe was started from another folder and python.dll wasn't in search path so obviously it can't run

Comment: @phuclv This is the point I have thought about. I have tried other two ways but all failed. First, I created a symbolic link for `python.dll` too and ran again, the command prompt told me that `can not start up the application`.  Second, I directly created a symbolic link for the whole python direcotry, but this symbolic link can Not be visited in command prompt even if I have added environment variables. Anyway, thanks for that you tried to help me :)

Comment: for a folder you need junction points instead of symlinks. But why do you want to do that? Why don't just use a normal shortcut?

Comment: @phuclv The reason why I do this thing is that I want to call different python versions (e.g. `python2.x` and `python3.x`) in cmd without using absolute path. So if I can create diffrent symlinks for different python versions, then I can just choose symlink to choose python version. Thanks for your attention, I will try other methods proposed in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows).

Comment: [This is an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). If you asked how to run multiple python versions then it'll be clear right from the beginning. There's no need to use symlink for that, a shortcut or an alias would help. Or just change `%PATH%`