# Running multiple instances of python in windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

I am using windows 11 and have installed python 2.7 first, and python 3.10 right after. I have set the environment path for both.

I have also made a copy of the python exe and renamed them to "python2" and "python3" (see below)

https://i.imgur.com/oZlL2iS.jpeg

https://i.imgur.com/MBRe9LL.jpeg

In the command prompt when I type "python - - version" it displays the last version of python I installed which is python 3. And when I type "python - 2 - - version" it displays the python 2 version I installed. Everything is working as it's suppose. (see below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB2sQ.png

Now at this point I created two different .py files (contents of files below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABL80.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O2op.jpg

The problem I am running into is that when I double click these python files, the command prompt opens and displays python 2.7 on both, even though I have the shebang line to associate with python 3 in one of the files.

In windows 10 which I set up many years ago, I have everything setup exactly the same, except for the python versions (I have python 2.7 and python 3.6). And when I double click the python 2 shebang file, the output is python 2.7, and when I double click the python 3 shebang file, it displays python 3.6.

How can I get this same outcome in windows 11? I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

I initially used the help from the answers given to the same question in windows 10 from many years ago, but these answers aren't working for windows 11. See below

[How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Don't add either to the path and use the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) normally installed with Python:

```py
    py -0             # List installed Pythons.
    py -2 script.py   # Run Python 2 (latest installed)
    py -3 script.py   # Run Python 3 (latest installed)
```

The environment variable `PY_PYTHON=M.m`, where `M.m` is the major/minor version, selects the default python to use for `py script.py`.  You can also add `.py;.pyw` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable so you can just run `script` without `py` or an extension.

Use `#!python2.7` at the top of scripts to override the default Python and use the specific version listed.  `#!\user\bin\python2.7` works too but doesn't need the full path on Windows.  The full path is needed for the script work on *nix.

Comment: This solution is not working on windows 11

Comment: @Richard What does "is not working" mean?  Are you using the standard installers from https://python.org?  Just typing "py" at a command prompt should run Python with the default options.  You *did* undo your mucking around with renaming and environment changes, right?

Answer (score 0):

As you are below python 3.7 you might have to use those shebang lines:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
```

For this to work you have to install the [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)

Beginngin with 3.7 you could loose the minor version and only use

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: These solutions do not work for me.