# VSCode: "Run" not running Python file in virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I used poetry to create a .venv folder in my project. If I use `poetry shell` to open a shell in the virtual environment and run my code with `python main.py` everything works as intended.

I used the "select environment" command to make sure VSCode uses that environment and it shows up correctly in the bottom right as `3.11.0 ('.venv': poetry)` and it works in so far that the editor recognizes my installed modules when autocompleting.

However when I right-click run `main.py` I get an Error that a module is not installed even though, as mentioned previously, it works fine when I run it from a shell in the virtual environment.

Is there some additional bit of configuration I'm missing so that "Run" will actually execute inside the venv?

Comment: what is "right-click run main.py"? where/what exactly do you right click? What exactly is the text/label of the thing that you click to run main.py?

Comment: "However when I right-click run main.py... Is there some additional bit of configuration I'm missing so that "Run" will actually execute inside the venv?" I can't understand. If you right-click on a file and choose Run, **what does that have to do with** Visual Studio Code? That sounds like something you're doing from within Windows itself, not related to either the editor or to Poetry.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367 answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use **Run Python File** or **Debug Python** file choices instead of Run code which is provided by other extension. This is displayed in the upper right corner of the editor.

[image]